# What to pass to Method that Checks if Key is Pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

Okay so I created a method called `KeyCheck()`, that should check if a key is pressed (specifically the enter key) and if it is it will press `button1`.

Unfortunately when I call the method I am unsure what to pass along to it. I want it to know when the enter key is being pressed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void GameStart()
    {
        richTextBox1.WordWrap = true;
        richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        richTextBox1.Text = "Hello, Welcome to Grandar!";
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GameStart();
        //What variable do I pass to KeyCheck Method?
        KeyCheck();
    }

    private void KeyCheck(KeyPressEventArgs k)
    {
        if (k.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to note here:

a) Do you really want to be calling `KeyCheck` directly as your sample code suggests or should it be wired up as a handler on the form (where the info you're asking will be automatically provided - will require a change in signature to align with the standard handlers as you have in some of your other methods).

b) I don't think you'll be able to call the `KeyCheck` method like you're doing unless you hook up another event to capture the keypress and then pass it to this method, by newing up a `new KeyPressEvent(...)`

Therefore, to answer your question, I think you'll want something like (pseudo-code)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GameStart();

    // Wire up a handler for the KeyPress event
    this.KeyPress += KeyCheck;
}

private void KeyCheck(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

You'll want something similar to your other methods, with the sender object and the event args.

```
if (e.KeyCode < Keys.Enter) {
    //Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

subscribe to this:

```
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.KeyPress_Method);
```

and the method to check the Enter key:

```
void KeyPress_Method(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // enter key
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```